# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un elemento dentro de un JSON anidado?

Tags: c#, json

Tengo una situación a resolver, es la siguiente:

en el JSON

```
{
    "Data1": null,
    "Data2": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NameSpace, Project.base.squema]], mscorlib",
        "$values": [{
            "Description": "Name LastName",
            "ID": "123456789"
        }]
    },
    "Type": 1
}
```

Cómo puedo acceder a los valores de los `Token  Description` y `ID`, es decir, leer el contenido de cada uno de ellos (`Name LastName` y `12345789`).

Comment: bienvenido stackoverflow en español.
Te paso 2 enlaces donde te explican detalladamente. - JavaScriptSerializer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856846/deserialize-a-json-array-in-c-sharp - Newtonsoft: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481569/how-to-get-json-array-in-c-sharp Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Probaste con JsonConvert de la libreria Newtonsoft.Json?

La sintaxis seria basicamente esta:

```
TuObjeto objetoDeserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TuObjeto>(tuJson);
```

Luego de que lo tengas mapeado a un objeto que conozcas peudes usarlo como cualquier otro de C#, es decir

```
TuObjeto.TuPropiedad.TuDato;
```

Espero haberte ayudado!